# Using IP tables to forward all requests to another internal IP?

Tags: networking, router, dns, port-forwarding, iptables

I have a network which is setup to be "mobile." It contains a few different servers. Everything works perfectly from the outside. What I'm trying to configure is the internal connections.

I have a DD-WRT router we can nickname `main` and another router we can call `generic`. The idea here is that `main` contains a host of portforwards and static IP allocations for my servers on it's own independent DHCP server. `Generic` is any router that I want `main` to access the internet through. (`Main` is connected to `generic`'s WiFi and uses its external IP)

In my current case `Generic` is a run-of-the-mill Router/Modem all-in-one from my ISP. All ports on `generic` are forwarded to `main`. This works. From the outside everything connects correctly.

However, because `generic` is inbetween `main` and the internet, hairpin-routing doesn't work.

To solve this I have some DNSMasq settings on `main` that pair `myDomain.com` with `10.0.0.101`. That looks like this...

```
address=/mydomain.com/10.0.0.101
```

Both `10.0.0.101` and `10.0.0.102` are Debian servers. `10.0.0.101` is the "administrative" server in my networks. It handles email, and some other administrative stuff.

I'm attempting to use IP Tables on `10.0.0.101` to simulate the effect of being outside the network. (Any port on myDomain.com should do the same thing regardless of whether or not I'm inside or outside the LAN.)

The ports that need to go to `10.0.0.102` are `80`, `8080`, `3000`, `22`, `9090`, `9091`, `9092` and `9093`. I'm not that familiar with IP Tables but found [this tutorial](http://www.debiantutorials.com/port-forwarding-with-iptables/).

I logged in as root and ran...

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Then I ran the following replacing `(MY_LOCAL_PORT)` with each of the ports I listed above...

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 0/0 -d 10.0.0.101 --dport (MY_LOCAL_PORT) -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.102:(MY_LOCAL_PORT)
```

I then ran...

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -d 10.0.0.102 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.101
```

This is not working. `traceroute` for `mydomain.com:22` yields `10.0.0.101`. I cannot view the webserver at `myDomain.com` even though I can view it by entering `10.0.0.102` in my browser's address bar.

What's the problem? How do I achieve this result? And as a bonus...can this be done on `main` rather than `10.0.0.101`?

Comment: While this is possible, you’ll effectively duplicate the current port forwardinds to yet another location. Not a great idea. Instead, you should try to somehow use `main`’s “WAN” IP address in the `address=` line. This could probably accomplished with some scripts and the `addn-hosts` file.

Comment: I would rather have everything in `main`. Howevet, I tried to do this by putting the Router's static IP (10.0.0.1) in the address field. That didn't work. I'd rather avoid having to change to the WAN IP (192.168.0.10) Because that will change when the network moves.

Comment: No, you misunderstand. You wouldn’t *change* the WAN IP, but just use it. And, most importantly, stay updated on its changes. However, I’m not familiar with the script hooks DD-WRT offers. To use hairpin NAT on `main`, you need its WAN IP address.

Comment: The WAN IP of `main` is the static IP assigned by `generic.` If `generic` were to change, it is likely that the static IP assigned by `generic`, and therefore `main`'s WAN IP, would change also.

Comment: I just tried that anyways. It worked in someways but caused some gnarly hostname issues.